# How do i make this shopping basket work and only let it show up if something has been added. using vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have tried many different ways but end up deleting everything and starting over. How do i make this work? learning from seeing how its done will help me a lot!

> this space is for shopping cart items. if its blank it does not show

```
<div id="gallery">
            
            <div id="cart" v-if="">
              <div class="card-body">
              <h6 class = "fw-light">Your Shopping Cart</h6>
          <!-- if add to basket is pressed on a specific item from the gallery then that item is added to the basket -->
          <ul>
            <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
              <div class="card">
              <b>{{item.name}}</b>
              <b>R{{item.price}}</b>
              <img :src="item.image" width="120px" height="auto">
              <button @click="deleteItem()" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-group-sm" >Remove Item</button>
              
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          </div>
      <!-- Add Total Item Count and Price Below Shopping Basket -->
        </div>
```

this is the  gallery below the shopping basket

```
        <ul>
          <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
            <div class = "card">
              <div id="pic"><img :src="item.image"/></div>
              <div class="card-header">
                <div >
                  <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
                  <p>{{item.description}}</p>
                  <h4>R {{item.price}}</h4>
                  <button @click="add2cart()" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Add to Basket</button>
                </div>
              </div>
          </li>
        </ul>  
      </div>
```

> The Vue Object is below. i am trying to keep it as simple as possible. i just want to add items from the gallery buttons to the basket.

```
<script src = "https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script>
    let galleryItems = new Vue({
        el: '#gallery', 
        data: {
          items: [{
              id : 1,
              name : 'Double King Sized Bed', 
              image : 'images/beds/bigWhiteBed.jpg',
              price : 20000, 
              description : 'A double king sized bed with a white interior and a black cover'
            },
            {
              id : 2, 
              name : 'Queen Sized Bed with Storage Drawers', 
              image : 'images/beds/darkDrawerBed.jpg', 
              price : 15000, 
              description : 'A queen sized bed with a dark storage drawer'
            },
            {
              id : 3, 
              name : 'King Sized Bed', 
              image : 'images/beds/fancyBed.jpg', 
              price : 12000, 
              description : 'A king sized bed with a white interior and a black cover'
            },
            {
              id : 4, 
              name : 'Pine King', 
              image : 'images/beds/fancyPineBed.jpg', 
              price : 8000, 
              description : 'A twin sized bed with a white interior and a black cover'
            },
            {
              id : 5, 
              name : 'Queen Sized Bed', 
              image : 'images/beds/royalBed.jpg', 
              price : 15000, 
              description : 'A queen sized bed with a white interior and a black cover'
            },
            {
              id : 6, 
              name : 'Glass coffee table', 
              image : 'images/coffee/glassCoffeeTable.jpg', 
              price : 3000, 
              description : 'Stylish Glass Coffee table'},
            {
              id : 7, 
              name : 'Wooden coffee table', 
              image : 'images/coffee/whiteCoffeeTable.jpg', 
              price : 2000, 
              description : 'White Coffee table'},
            {
              id : 8, 
              name : 'Wooden Coffee Table on wheels', 
              image : 'images/coffee/whitewheelCoffeeTable.jpg', 
              price : 3000, 
              description : 'Easy To Move coffee table'},
            {
              id : 9, 
              name : 'Two Piece Coffee table set', 
              image : 'images/coffee/yellowCoffeeTableSet.jpg', 
              price : 2000, 
              description : 'Two tables One Price'},
            {
              id : 10, 
              name : 'Large Black Leather L-Shaped home Cinema Couch', 
              image : 'images/couches/blackLshape.jpg', 
              price : 30000, 
              description : 'Stylish Black Leather L-Shaped home Cinema Couch '},
            {
              id : 11, 
              name : 'White Leather reading Lounger', 
              image : 'images/couches/fancyChair.jpg', 
              price : 30000, description : 'Single seated Reading chair'},
            {
              id : 12, 
              name : 'Black and white Home office desk', 
              image : 'images/desks/blackAndWhiteDesk.jpg', 
              price : 2000, 
              description : 'A Stylish Work Station'},
            {
              id : 13, 
              name : 'Large L-Shaped Work Station', 
              image : 'images/desks/LshapeOffice.jpg', 
              price : 4000, 
              description : 'A spacious Corner Unit Desk'},
            {
              id : 14, 
              name : 'Combined Leisure and Home Office Station', 
              image : 'images/desks/officeBed.jpg', 
              price : 13000, 
              description : 'Combine work, relaxation and Play'},
            {
              id : 15, 
              name : 'Truss Table styled desks', 
              image : 'images/desks/trussTableOfficeDesk.jpg', 
              price : 1500, 
              description : 'Easy to assemble and move'},
            {
              id : 16, 
              name : 'Jet Black Chair', 
              image : 'images/misc/blackChair.jpg', 
              price : 1000, 
              description : 'A chair for any Environment'},
            {
              id : 17, 
              name : 'Dinning Room Table', 
              image : 'images/misc/whiteDiningRoomTable.jpg', 
              price : 10000, description : 'Dining Room Table for the family'}
                ],
              },
```

> I know these methods are wrong. i added them like this to show what i was struggling with.

```
              methods: {
                add2cart(){
                  this.items.push({items});
                },
                deleteItem(){
                this.myList.splice(this.myList.indexOf(this.myList[0]), 1);
              }
    } });
    </script>
```

Comment: I dont know if i get this straight, but you want to add the whole object "Items" to the basket?

Comment: No, thats just the way ive left it for now. but i wan them to appear only one at at a time if they sare chosen from the gallery. i am very new to this so i did not realize that it was all going to display.

Answer (score 0):

This might attend you well:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="gallery"> 
      <h6>Products: </h6>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(product, i) in products" :key="i" style="text-align: left;">

          <b>{{product.name}}</b>
          <b>R{{product.price}}</b>
          
          <button @click="addProduct(product)" style="width: 50px; margin: 0px 5px;" >
            Add
          </button>          
        </li>
      </ul>      
      <hr>

      <h6>Basket: </h6>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" style="text-align: left;">

          <b>{{item.name}}</b>
          <b>R{{item.price}}</b>          

          <button @click="deleteItem(i)" >
            Remove 
          </button>          
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      products: [
        {
          id : 1,
          name : 'Double King Sized Bed', 
          image : 'images/beds/bigWhiteBed.jpg',
          price : 20000, 
          description : 'A double king sized bed with a white interior and a black cover'
        },
        {
          id : 2, 
          name : 'Queen Sized Bed with Storage Drawers', 
          image : 'images/beds/darkDrawerBed.jpg', 
          price : 15000, 
          description : 'A queen sized bed with a dark storage drawer'
        },
        {
          id : 3, 
          name : 'King Sized Bed', 
          image : 'images/beds/fancyBed.jpg', 
          price : 12000, 
          description : 'A king sized bed with a white interior and a black cover'
        }
      ],
      items: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
        addProduct(product){
          this.items.push(product);
        },
        deleteItem(index){
          this.items.splice(index, 1);        
        }
    }

 };
```

Codesandbox working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-river-9cpim?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: I Had Previously tried that route however i am supposed to use vue in the format in my code. with "let galleryItems = new Vue..."

Comment: just grab the code and put inside the unpkg format, i just did an example, you can completely take the example and put inside what you want.